# Are cloth diapers really supposed to fit a newborn?

Tags: newborn, cloth-diaper

We decided to go with a diaper service before our son was born but when we brought him home the diapers seems **way** to large for him. He was small, but not insanely small (6 lbs 10 oz). Only the Newborn sized disposable diapers seemed to fit. And what was strange was that most stores don't seem to sell Newborn sized diapers, they almost all seem to sell only size 1 and up.

Am I wrong is thinking that my son really isn't exceptionally tiny? At what weight are "newborn" cloth diapers supposed to fit?

Comment: That's 3 kilograms, which is perfectly normal and average and not particularly small at all.

Comment: We had ours in cloth diapers from the start - about a pound heavier than yours. We had prefolds and folded them differently when she was a newborn vs. 6 weeks vs. now (10 months).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because newborns grow so quickly, the smallest diapers will seem very large at first. We put ours in cloth around 1 month old, and they fit much better than at birth. Ours was around 9 or 10 pounds by 1 month.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same thing, probably because they are that size for just a short time. They never fit like a tailored suit, they just need to "catch stuff".